# How do I limit google places autocomplete results to city and country only, in Angular?

Tags: angular, google-places-api

I'm using ngx-google-places-autocomplete in my angular project, and I need to limit the enabled addresses to be from one city only.

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>address</mat-label>
    <input #address ngx-google-places-autocomplete [autocomplete]="autocomplete" type="text" matInput ngDefaultControl  [(ngModel)]="user.user_address">
  </mat-form-field>
```

In order to limit the results I tried this code in the TS:

```
  autocomplete!:any;
  @ViewChild ('address', {static:false}) address!: HTMLInputElement;
  
constructor()
{
      var options = {
        types: ['(cities)'],
        componentRestrictions: {country: "UK"}
       };

      this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.address, options);
}
```

But it doesn't work, it brings addresses from all over the world...

How can I limit it?

Thanks a lot.